# Get columns from one table to another

Tags: sql

So I'll create a combination of all first names and all surnames from a table (Person).

```
insert into tabell_med_navn 
select f.fornavn, e.etternavn
from person f cross join person e
```

These combinations should then be added to a table I have made earlier.

```
create table tabell_med_navn (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  fornavn varchar(40) null,
  etternavn varchar(40) null,
  primary key (id)
);
```

It is when I am trying to send the combination over it fails. Anybody know why it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List the columns being inserted:

```
insert into tabell_med_navn (fornavn, etternavn)
    select f.fornavn, e.etternavn
    from person f cross join
         person e;
```

This will assign a default value to the id column.

Comment: ... and maybe you want to `select distinct f.fornavn, e.etternavn` in order not to get duplicates.